# DataFrame.from_dict fails to change dict with tuple keys into multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I feel very confused with DataFrame.from_dict. It seems DataFrame.from_dict works right on dict with tuple dict accidentally @_@. Seriously, I have tried some cases below.

**case1:**

```
dict_var1 = {('a', 'b'): [43,47], ('a', 'c'): [23,40], ('b', 'c'): [30,35], ('c', 'd'): [10,30], ('a', 'd'): [23,28]}
frame_var1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_var1, orient='index', columns=['num', 'cnt'])
print(frame_var1.index)
```

**result1:**

> Index([('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('a', 'd')], dtype='object')

**case2:**

```
dict_var2 = {('a', 'b'): {'num': 43, 'cnt': 47}, ('a', 'c'): {'num': 23, 'cnt': 40}, ('b', 'c'): {'num': 30, 'cnt': 35}, ('c', 'd'): {'num': 10, 'cnt': 30}, ('a', 'd'): {'num': 23, 'cnt': 28}}
frame_var2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_var2, orient='index', columns=['num', 'cnt'])
print(frame_var2.index)
```

**result2:**

> MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c', 'd']],
>              labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 1, 2]])

**question**:

When I change the type of dict values from list to dict, DataFrame.from_dict can change the tuple dict keys into multi-index right. Could anyone explain how DataFrame.from_dict works leading to these results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on the [document](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/frame.py#L905-L985)

> ```
> if orient == 'index':
>     if len(data) > 0:
>         # TODO speed up Series case
>         if isinstance(list(data.values())[0], (Series, dict)):
>             data = _from_nested_dict(data)
>         else:
>             data, index = list(data.values()), list(data.keys())
> ```

So in your case the second one pass the `isinstance`, then will

```
data = _from_nested_dict(data)
```

But the first one values type is list , then

```
data, index = list(data.values()), list(data.keys())
```

Comment: OK. Thanks for the source code. I think checking the dict keys whether to be tuple or not, and then trying to change the keys to index or multi-index may be a little better.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't 100% answer but just to show that you can get it to work with `dict_var1` the same way as `dict_var2` works.

The cause for this is an implementation detail. But it looks like `pd.DataFrame` (or `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(..., orient='columns')`) favours `dict_var1` if you present it in a columnar fashion:

```
frame_var1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_var1, index=['num', 'cnt']).T
print(frame_var1)
     num  cnt
a b   43   47
  c   23   40
b c   30   35
c d   10   30
a d   23   28
```

Whereas `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(..., orient='index')` favours `dict_var2` with the keys as the index.

```
frame_var2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    dict_var2, orient='index', columns=['num', 'cnt'])
print(frame_var2)
     num  cnt
a b   43   47
  c   23   40
  d   23   28
b c   30   35
c d   10   30
```

Let me know if I can explain further.

Comment: Thanks for your solution very much. I just feel that using transpose seems not to be  symmetrical with respect to the operations on 'columns' psychologically.